# How to do allocation of pointers in subroutines when using OpenMP?

Tags: pointers, fortran, openmp, allocation, fortran2003

As the following code sample shows, the main program tries to utilize OpenMP to call a subroutine. In that subroutine, a local pointer variable is created and iterated. The program generates `Subscript #1 of the array PTEMPINTLIST has value 208 which is greater than the upper bound of 207` errors (the specific numbers vary). I have already make the encompassing user-derived type `omp-private`, but it seems the local variables in the invoked subroutines should also be declared `omp-private`, but I am not sure whether this is true and I don't know how to achieve this.

Could you help to comment why the program gives such error? More importantly, could you help to comment the best practices concerning how to do allocation of pointers in subroutines when using OpenMP?

#### No idea why the fortran code is not colored. Could someone help to comment how to color the code, so that it is more readable?

#### The compiler is Intel Fortran Compiler, and the version is as the follows:

```
[root@localhost new]# ifort --version
ifort (IFORT) 12.1.0 20111011
Copyright (C) 1985-2011 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

#### The error message is shown below:

```
[root@localhost new]# ifort test_omp.f90 -warn -check -g -trace -openmp -static
[root@localhost new]# ./a.out 
 Thread numbers are:            8
 Thread            0  -            1
 Thread            0  -            2
 Thread            0  -            3
 Thread            0  -            4
 Thread            0  -            5
 Thread            0  -            6
 Thread            0  -            7
 Thread            0  -            8
 Thread            0  -            9
 Thread            0  -           10
 Thread numbers are:            8
 Thread            7  -            1
 Thread            7  -            2
 Thread            7  -            3
 Thread            7  -            4
 Thread            7  -            5
 Thread            7  -            6
 Thread            7  -            7
 Thread            7  -            8
 Thread            7  -            9
 Thread            7  -           10
 Thread            7  -           11
 Thread            7  -           12
 Thread            7  -           13
 Thread            7  -           14
 Thread            7  -           15
 Thread            7  -           16
 Thread            7  -           17
 Thread            7  -           18
 Thread            7  -           19
 Thread            7  -           20
 Thread            7  -           21
 Thread            7  -           22
 Thread            7  -           23
 Thread            7  -           24
 Thread            7  -           25
 Thread            7  -           26
 Thread            7  -           27
 Thread            7  -           28
 Thread            7  -           29
 Thread            7  -           30
 Thread            7  -           31
 Thread            7  -           32
 Thread            7  -           33
 Thread            7  -           34
 Thread            7  -           35
 Thread            7  -           36
 Thread            7  -           37
 Thread            7  -           38
 Thread            7  -           39
 Thread            7  -           40
 Thread            7  -           41
 Thread            7  -           42
 Thread            7  -           43
 Thread            7  -           44
 Thread            7  -           45
 Thread            7  -           46
 Thread            7  -           47
 Thread            7  -           48
 Thread            7  -           49
 Thread            7  -           50
 Thread            7  -           51
 Thread            7  -           52
 Thread            7  -           53
 Thread            7  -           54
 Thread            7  -           55
 Thread            7  -           56
 Thread            7  -           57
 Thread            7  -           58
 Thread            7  -           59
 Thread            7  -           60
 Thread            7  -           61
 Thread            7  -           62
 Thread            7  -           63
 Thread            7  -           64
 Thread            7  -           65
 Thread            7  -           66
 Thread            7  -           67
 Thread            7  -           68
 Thread            7  -           69
 Thread            7  -           70
 Thread            7  -           71
 Thread            7  -           72
 Thread            7  -           73
 Thread            7  -           74
 Thread            7  -           75
 Thread            7  -           76
 Thread            7  -           77
 Thread            7  -           78
 Thread            7  -           79
 Thread            7  -           80
 Thread            7  -           81
 Thread            7  -           82
 Thread            7  -           83
 Thread            7  -           84
 Thread            7  -           85
 Thread            7  -           86
 Thread            7  -           87
 Thread            7  -           88
 Thread            7  -           89
 Thread            7  -           90
 Thread            7  -           91
 Thread            7  -           92
 Thread            7  -           93
 Thread            7  -           94
 Thread            7  -           95
 Thread            7  -           96
 Thread            7  -           97
 Thread            7  -           98
 Thread            7  -           99
 Thread            7  -          100
 Thread            7  -          101
 Thread            7  -          102
 Thread            7  -          103
 Thread            7  -          104
 Thread            7  -          105
 Thread            7  -          106
 Thread            7  -          107
 Thread            7  -          108
 Thread            7  -          109
 Thread            7  -          110
 Thread            7  -          111
 Thread            7  -          112
 Thread            7  -          113
 Thread            7  -          114
 Thread            7  -          115
 Thread            7  -          116
 Thread            7  -          117
 Thread            7  -          118
 Thread            7  -          119
 Thread            7  -          120
 Thread            7  -          121
 Thread            7  -          122
 Thread            7  -          123
 Thread            7  -          124
 Thread            7  -          125
 Thread            7  -          126
 Thread            7  -          127
 Thread            7  -          128
 Thread            7  -          129
 Thread            7  -          130
 Thread            7  -          131
 Thread            7  -          132
 Thread            7  -          133
 Thread            7  -          134
 Thread            7  -          135
 Thread            7  -          136
 Thread            7  -          137
 Thread            7  -          138
 Thread            7  -          139
 Thread            7  -          140
 Thread            7  -          141
 Thread            7  -          142
 Thread            7  -          143
 Thread            7  -          144
 Thread            7  -          145
 Thread            7  -          146
 Thread            7  -          147
 Thread            7  -          148
 Thread            7  -          149
 Thread            7  -          150
 Thread            7  -          151
 Thread            7  -          152
 Thread            7  -          153
 Thread            7  -          154
 Thread            7  -          155
 Thread            7  -          156
 Thread            7  -          157
 Thread            7  -          158
 Thread            7  -          159
 Thread            7  -          160
 Thread            7  -          161
 Thread            7  -          162
 Thread            7  -          163
 Thread            7  -          164
 Thread            7  -          165
 Thread            7  -          166
 Thread            7  -          167
 Thread            7  -          168
 Thread            7  -          169
 Thread            7  -          170
 Thread            7  -          171
 Thread            7  -          172
 Thread            7  -          173
 Thread            7  -          174
 Thread            7  -          175
 Thread            7  -          176
 Thread            7  -          177
 Thread            7  -          178
 Thread            7  -          179
 Thread            7  -          180
 Thread            7  -          181
 Thread            7  -          182
 Thread            7  -          183
 Thread            7  -          184
 Thread            7  -          185
 Thread            7  -          186
 Thread            7  -          187
 Thread            7  -          188
 Thread            7  -          189
 Thread            7  -          190
 Thread            7  -          191
 Thread            7  -          192
 Thread            7  -          193
 Thread            7  -          194
 Thread            7  -          195
 Thread            7  -          196
 Thread            7  -          197
 Thread            7  -          198
 Thread            7  -          199
 Thread            7  -          200
 Thread            7  -          201
 Thread            7  -          202
 Thread            7  -          203
 Thread            7  -          204
 Thread            7  -          205
 Thread            7  -          206
 Thread            7  -          207
forrtl: severe (408): fort: (2): Subscript #1 of the array PTEMPINTLIST has value 208 which is greater than the upper bound of 207

Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              00000000004F0C6A  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              00000000004EF766  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000426700  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              000000000040235F  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000402881  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000400D09  testopenmp_1_allo          39  omp.f90
a.out              00000000004006BE  MAIN__                     23  omp.f90
a.out              00000000004A4CF3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

#### The code sample is:

```
    module MyModule
        type :: MyType
            integer, dimension(:), pointer :: pIntList => null ()
        end type 
    end module MyModule

    program TestOpenMP_1_AllocationWithinSubroutines

        use MyModule
        use omp_lib
        implicit none

        type(MyType) :: instance
        integer :: threadCount 
        integer :: threadId 
        integer :: I

!$omp parallel private (instance, threadCount, threadId, I)
        threadCount = OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()
        write (*,*) 'Thread numbers are: ', threadCount
        threadId = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
        allocate (instance%pIntList(200 + threadId))
        CALL IterateList(instance) 
!$omp end parallel

        read (*,*)

    contains

        subroutine IterateList(aInstance)
            type(MyType) :: aInstance
            integer, dimension(:), pointer :: pTempIntList => null()
            integer :: threadId
            threadId = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
            allocate (pTempIntList(size(aInstance%pIntList)))
            do I = 1, size(pTempIntList)
                pTempIntList(I) = I 
                !write (*,*) pTempIntList(I)
                write (*,*) 'Thread ',threadId, ' - ',pTempIntList(I)
            end do          
        end subroutine 

    end program TestOpenMP_1_AllocationWithinSubroutines
```

Comment: shouldn't you have allocatable keyword?

Comment: The reason has been written at the beginning. What do you mean by `the other one was already answered...???`? The reason of the strange error is still NOT clear, with NO official or reliable information to learn to fight against future errors, if you have read the questions. Furthermore, here, the emphasis is put in a clearer way on how OpenMP managed the allocation of pointer types.

Comment: Do *not* ask the *same exact question* more than once.  Doing so may result in your posts being flagged which may result in further moderator action.

Answer (score 3):

With the subroutine contained in the main program gfortran gives the error message: "At line 36 of file test_OpenMP.f90 / Fortran runtime error: Loop variable has been modified"

Apparently the size of "pTempIntList" is always set to the same value (varying between runs), apparently using size(aInstance%pIntList) for a random thread.   Which is too small for threads past the that thread.  Below is a version that works.   Removing "=> null ()" seems to be necessary, for both gfortran and ifort.   I don't know whether that is supposed to be the case, but since two compilers require it...

Try this version:

```
module MyModule
  type :: MyType
      integer, dimension(:), pointer :: pIntList
  end type

contains
   subroutine IterateList(aInstance)
      use omp_lib
      integer :: I
      type(MyType) :: aInstance
      integer, dimension(:), pointer :: pTempIntList
      integer :: threadId
      threadId = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
      allocate (pTempIntList(size(aInstance%pIntList)))
      do I = 1, size(pTempIntList)
          write (*, *) i, threadID, size(aInstance%pIntList), size (pTempIntList)
          pTempIntList(I) = I
      end do
   end subroutine IterateList

end module MyModule

program TestOpenMP_1_AllocationWithinSubroutines

   use MyModule
   use omp_lib
   implicit none

   type(MyType) :: instance
   integer :: threadCount
   integer :: threadId
   integer :: I

   !$omp parallel private (instance, threadCount, threadId, I)
   threadCount = OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()
   write (*,*) 'Thread numbers are: ', threadCount
   threadId = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
   allocate (instance%pIntList(200 + threadId))
   CALL IterateList(instance)
   !$omp end parallel

end program TestOpenMP_1_AllocationWithinSubroutines
```

Comment: Thank you for your workaround very much! Nonetheless, do you know the reason of the problems? I mean, in the real code (a little bit more real than the sample), this strange exception still occurs. I wonder if I could post the code (~1000 lines) without destroying your patience...

Comment: No, I don't know the reason.   Do you need a pointer or could you use an allocatable?   If an allocatable will work, I suggest trying that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're running into the problem that initialization of a variable gives it the `save` attribute. The initialization of `pTempIntList` with the null pointer means it gets saved between different invocations of the subroutine. I'm not sure of the particulars of the implementation, but a guess might be that all invocations of the subroutine actually share the memory for this variable.

You should really also seriously consider Anycorn's comment. It's usually much safer to use allocatable variables than pointers. If it can be done with allocatables, use them.